# Collect data from last 5 days in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have following code

```
    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    public function ip2_exists() {

        global $db,$date;

        $code = $db->select("imp","id",array("date"=>$date,"ip"=>$this->ip()));
        if($code->num_rows<1){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

It collects the current day data and it works fine. But I want to collect the last 5 days date.

How to do that in php?

Comment: Hi,
Anyone haven't here?
Please I need your help.

Comment: I added an answer that I had deleted a couple of times. Try it out

Comment: What framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");

public function ip2_exists()
{

    global $db,$date;

    // Used to keep count track
    $countDays = 0;

    // Default return of true
    $checkedData = true;

    while($countDays < 5)
    {
        $code = $db->select("imp","id",array("date"=>$date,"ip"=>$this->ip()));
        if($code->num_rows < 1)
        {
            $checkedData = false;
        }

        $countDays++;
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $date." -1 day"));
    }

    return $checkedData;
}
```

Comment: Instead of "date" => $date , you can use date between date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $date." -5 day")) , date("Y-m-d") and groub by date field, and condition is to set ( $code->num_rows < 5) it return false else true. it reduces the number of times query executed and avoiding the usage of conditional statement here(WHILE)